# For loop with awk command in the body not working

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
for i in test1.txt do awk '$1==$i {sum +=$4}END {print sum}' test2.txt
```

Where test1.txt looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

But it's not working. What I want to achieve is, for each letter within *test1.txt* file, find all the rows of *test2.txt* that have the same letter in their first column, and for those rows, sum all their values in the 4<sup>th</sup> column.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how  `test2.txt` look like, and how you want output to look like ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` alone here.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} ($1 in a) {sum+=$4} END{print sum}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this does not work the way you have written it is that `awk` will interpret `$i` as "the `i`th field", and since the `awk` variable `i` has no value, you will get an error, or if you are using GNU `awk` or `mawk`, `$i` will be the same as `$0` which is the whole line (with `mawk` or GNU `awk`, the program looks for lines whose first column is the same as the whole line).

Instead, to "import" you shell variable into `awk`:

```
awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i { sum += $4 } END { print sum }' test2.txt
```

Also, the value of the shell variable `$i` will only ever be the name of the file `test1.txt` (since this is what you loop over).

To loop over the *contents* of the file:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    awk ...as above...
done <test1.txt
```

[αғsнιη's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433510/116858) shows how you can do this without using a shell loop.

Comment: Alternatively, one could put the variable into `awk`'s environment and use `ENVIRON["i"]`